# How to make ChannelAdvisor send orders to my application?

Tags: php, api, integration

I'm writing a php application which would do something with orders from ChannelAdvisor (CA).

Currently, I use CA API to get orders, and setup a cronjob which get orders from CA every minute, but this is not a good practice as my system need to process those orders in time. So, I'm finding a way to have my application receive CA orders right after placed.

In Shopify, they have webhook notification which would send json to a specific URL whenever an order was placed, is there something like that in CA?

Comment: how do you get client account for testing while development?

Answer (score 0):

Channeladvisor does not support webhooks or realtime notifications of any sort.
Scheduling an import (as you are) is as efficient as it will get.

Keep in mind that there are several delays before an order actually is served up for import.

It must first pass the marketplace's fraud checking, then channel advisors internal worker must import the order into their system, and finally your scheduler will pull in the order.

If you need timely orders it's best to connect directly to the marketplace and cut out the middleman.